# Azure Topic Subscription Rule created with Service Bus Explorer not triggering

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am using Service Bus Explorer as a quick way of testing a rule that does not work when deployed via ARM.

In JavaScript in the Azure Function I am setting the Topic message to:

```
context.bindings.outputSbMsg = { Indicator: 'Itinerary'};
```

In Service Bus Explorer I am setting a Rule on a Subscription with this string:

```
Indicator = 'Itinerary'
```

But messages sent to the Topic do not go to this Subscription ( they go to another with the rule 1 = 1)

Question: What am I missing here?

Supplementary info:

1. I do not seem to have access to the Indicator property. As a test I created an action on the  1=1 rule that appended to the Indicator property and the result was empty.
2. I am able to access the Indicator property in JavaScript if I have a Function that is triggered by the 1 = 1 rule, so the property is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule doesn't work because

1. The rule works against system or user-defined properties rather than message body.
2. What js function outputs is merely message body, i.e. `context.bindings.outputSbMsg = { Indicator: 'Itinerary'};` sends a message `{ Indicator: 'Itinerary'}` and no property is set by us.

And the default rule with 1=1 true filter enables all messages to be selected into the subscription, so you see messages went there all the time. Check [doc of topic filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) for more details.

For now, it's [by design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52901360/azure-function-service-bus-output-message-properties) that js function output can't populate message properties. To make the filter work, we have to send messages with property using SDK instead. Install `azure-sb` package then try sample code below.

```
const azuresb = require("azure-sb");
const connStr = "ServiceBusConnectionString";
const mytopic = "mytopic";

var serviceBus = azuresb.createServiceBusService(connStr);
const msg =
{
  body: "Testing",
  customProperties: {
    Indicator: 'Itinerary'
  }
};
serviceBus.sendTopicMessage(mytopic, msg, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        context.log(error);
    }
    else{
        context.log("Message Sent");
    }
});
```